# Nested list in react and prisma ORM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, prisma

I need subindexes to be created from indexes and for each index to be able to upload files. At the end I will have a folder with subfolders with their respective documents.

**1. title01**

1.1. subtitle01
doc.word

1.2. subtitle02

1.2.1. sub-subtitle01
doc.word
doc.PDF

**2. title02**

2.1. subtitle01

2.1.1 sub-subtitle01
doc.PDF

I'm trying to use recursion but I'm not very good at it. I have also looked for alternatives but I can't find something that looks like what I want

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.